# Google Maps v3 - Overriding Default SmoothZoom Behavior

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is there a way to prevent a Google Map from automatically doing the Smooth Zoom transition when zooming in or out? I would like it to just snap to the desired zoom level.

In the ModestMaps Library for Flash, for example, I can set zoomDuration to 0 to force all transitions to be instant rather than animated.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by calling `setCenter`

```
map.setCenter(latlng, zoomLevel);
```

Should work in Maps API V3.